# how to handle error post route express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, express-router

I am trying when someone sends a post request on the wrong Id then send it back automatically but my code is not responding like that,

here is my code sample

```
   try {
                const updateFolder = {
                    folderName: pureFolderName,
                    userId: purePartnerName,
                    slug: pureslug,
                    folderImage: audioFolderImage,
                };
                const audioFolder = await AudioFolder.update(updateFolder, {
                    where: { slug: updateSlug },
                });
                if (audioFolder) {
                    res.status(200).redirect('/admin/audio-folder');
                } else {
                    req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong into Inserting data !');
                    return res.status(302).redirect('back');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                if (error) {
                    req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong into Inserting data !');
                    return res.status(302).redirect('back');
                }
            }
```

it's showing this on browser `Cannot POST /admin/audio-folder/edit/`

can anyone give me info about how to handle this?

Comment: is there anyone?

Comment: Your problem is not in this part of the code. It is in the place you send this request: `/admin/audio-folder/edit/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (I believe) is that the route cannot accept a `POST` request.

does your code look like

```js
router.get('/ROUTE', async (req, res, next) => {
 // code
});
```

or

```js
router.post('/ROUTE', async (req, res, next) => {
 // code
});
```

the first only accepts `GET` requests, the second only `POST` requests.

Comment: yes @Lenshawn  your are right